# static linking with cross compiler

Tags: static, linker

My test.c program uses printf function. I want to statically link library I need. I use arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc cross compiler.

When I compile my code like this

arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc test.c -o test

it passes, but I think he still uses dynamic linking by looking at dissasembly of test.

So,what option should I add in order to statically link libc.a library?

Comment: Pass `-Wall` to get all warnings, and `-static` to ask for static linking to your cross-compiler `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`

Comment: Also, check by passing `-v` to your cross-compiler (in addition of other options) that it does what you want it to.

Comment: if I put arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -Wall -static test.c -o test, and then try to see disassembly, it goes wild. Looks like he get into some ethernal loop. And with -v option the disassembly looks the same as without all these options. So mabue I was wrong about assumption that he uses dynamic linking...Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc test.c -o test -Xlinker -static /path/to/libc.a
```

This worked for me. Also, it might complain that you don't have static libgcc_s. Then try this:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc test.c -o test -Xlinker -static /path/to/libc.a -static-libgcc
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it's built ok. But when running in qemu arm VM, it seg fault. If not statically built, it runs ok.